# Ingresar contraseña en Caja de texto HTML para descargar archivo

Tags: html, entrada, descarga, text

Estimados amigos del foro, saludos
Me gustaria lograr que en una cada de texto hecho en HTMl se pueda ingresar una contraseña y al darle click al boton se descargue una hoja de un archivo HCG de google drive. 
Para esto existe un codigo prefijo o raiz general en el codigo html y la contraseña corresponde al id de la hoja, asi de este modo cada id le entrego a un usuario (mis estudiantes) quienes deberan ingresar la contraseña (id) para que se descargue la hoja que le corresponde.
El archivo HCG tiene 30 hojas, cada una tiene su id al final en la url, tengo 30 estudiantes. Por lo tanto cada uno tiene su contraseña o id.
Espero que me haya dado a entedender lo que requiero.
Coloco el codigo html que hasta aqui tengo, el mismo que no descarga la hoja segun el id sino que siempre descarga la primera hoja.

```html
<HTML>
<!SOLICTAR AL USUARIO LA CLAVE>
  <BODY>   
    <H2>CONSULTA DE AVANCE DE NOTAS</H2>    
    <FORM name="validacion" action="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hSmI_Xn0MlvYr803A78lTdPVpSZCu9cSQw0wDO6I3qs/pdf?gid=" method="POST" target="resultado"> <!Esta es la raiz> 
      <P>Ingrese su contraseña de obtención de notas:  <INPUT type="text" name="entrada"> <!Este es el sufijo o id que se debe concatenar a la raiz. El campo sólo permite letras y números>  

      <INPUT type="submit" value="Obtener Notas" onClick="validate(entrada)" type="reset" ></P>

    </FORM>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Agradezco anticipadamente toda colaboración

Comment: Talvez sea algo parecido a tener que concatener las dos partes de la url la una antes del id y la otra la id   como esto: =CONCATENATE(“https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mRR4o3X7tM5PxEFW6KpTD-Pa9jeDYo3Bs1yn6O1wLCE/edit#gid=”; parametro_id) donde el parametro id es el especifico de cada hoja; este deberá ser ingresado en una caja de texto en la pantalla HTML y luego de pulsar el boton se abre esa exclusiva hoa

Comment: He probado con este código pero igualmente no funciona!!                                      <html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function clickyClick() {
            url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxx=' + document.getElementById("clavehoja").value
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form><h2>Ingrese su Clave:</h2>
    <input type="text" name="notaind" id="clavehoja">
    <button onclick="clickyClick()">Ver las notas</button>
  </form>

</body>
<html>